# Force index with php instead of .htaccess

Tags: php

Can't find any resources for this though I expect it to be easy enough, I just don't have the slightest idea how to do it myself. I need to force a dynamic directory to go to the inner index.php file. For example, if user goes to `website.com/directory` it should redirect to `website.com/directory/index.php` where directory is dynamic.

Any ideas? This has to be with php instead of .htaccess; thanks!

EDIT: To clarify i need the url to display `website.com/directory/index.php` instead of `website.com/directory` even if they user manually goes to `website.com/directory`

Comment: Isn't that apache's default behaviour?

Comment: By "dynamic directory", do you mean that this folder does not actually exist in the filing system?

Comment: i mean that this directory name can be anything because the file is copied when a new submission is made to the database, its what ever we name it on the admin side of the site.

Comment: That sounds like a poor design.

Comment: It's a flexible design. If the admin who is not a developer wants to make a new directory, he types in a name, hits submit and has a new directory added to navigation and so on. It works for that purpose but for my current purpose I have the problem above.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it,

```
    if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) !== 'index.php'){
       header("location:index.php");
       exit();
      }
```

Comment: you could get rid of that else and just throw an exit(); after your header("location:index.php"); line..  then throw your code underneath that if block.

Comment: you need to add this line to each file in every sub-directory of domain. It is not a good solution, But if it solve your purpose it's oks

Comment: @sanjeev no it's one dynamic file that is copied when ever a new directory is created so the code is the same for every page of this type, the differences are dynamic and so it doesnt need to be reposted or anything of that nature. its not for every page on the site, just those that are copied. I appreciate the warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the uri is not already index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php    [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I needed a php solution as mentioned in the post and title. Thank you though

Comment: I'm sorry... I misunderstood

Comment: Not a problem, it's good to have your answer there too incase anyone stumbles upon it via google or SO search and it is useful for them; for my specific problem I can't use .htaccess though. Thanks!