# Replicate the .htaccess behaviour with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

I am having a problem , I am a great supporter of .htaccess , but I have taken a yahoo small business hosting for one of my Project, which currently dont supports .htaccess rewrite, so I am looking for some best option to mimic the same functionality with php instead of .htaccess

So , I can redirect all request to index.php with the following code, [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060700/force-index-with-php-instead-of-htaccess)

```
if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) !== 'index.php'){
       header("location:index.php");
       exit();
 }
```

Now I want to implement other functionality in php too, like denial of directory access, and allowing only css , jss , image file etc direct access.So please suggest me some optimised and feasilble way to achieve this. Here is .htaccess for reference

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
#SetEnv FACEBOOK_APP_ID 4343434343
#SetEnv FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET     d00b24f1344334833c90f0795ebe
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

# This denies all web access to your .ini file. 

<Files ~ "\.(php|ini|log|htm)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
    Allow from All
</FilesMatch>

<files config.base.ini>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
<files errorlogs.log>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
```

***PS :FB SECRET ID AND CREDENTIALS ARE DUMMY***

Comment: Thanks for sharing your secrets with us ;)

Comment: @veritas so you think those FB credentials are correct huh ? You are wrong my friend, Anyways you are free to use it. Hail DATA liberation

Comment: I don't know/care ;)

Comment: Regarding your question, the problem will be that user won't be redirected to your script when the URL differs from index.php (or any other .php script).

Comment: Hard to believe why would anyone want to do this. Developers tend to do the reverse i.e. move these directives from PHP to htaccess. All these simple 2-3 line blocks in htaccess will make long code in PHP.

Comment: @anubhava yes , being a fan of htaccess its hard for me too, but yahoo small business doesnt support htaccess currently !

Comment: That's really awful. It will require lot of PHP code to do this.